# How do I get the details of an Amazon product from a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to enter a URL (E.g: `https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0BQ732228/`) and get some details from it, such as the title, price, and cover image, ideally using JS or Jquery.
This would have to be client side, without involving a server.

I've tried searching online for an API, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: What is the use case for this?  There are some APIs. https://rapidapi.com/collection/amazon-products

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem quite possible to accomplish this on the client side. The reason is that cross-origin requests are limited in client-side operations. This limitation is in place to maintain browser security and web standards. Therefore, using just JavaScript or jQuery on the client side may not allow you to make cross-origin requests to retrieve a web page's content.